# How to dig into Exception data in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I'm finding it hard to find the answer to my query in existing answers of Stackoverflow that's why I've decided to ask the question.

I want to handle the error with Try Catch but the default information from e.Message is not what I need.

Basically when using a breakpoint I can see that the Exception object has the data available when I dig in.

[image]

The PositionMessage type is string so I want to use this data to feed into Catch behavior. I just can't figure out how to assign the value from this specific field into a variable.

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Aside from a message, an [Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) can also have an inner exception

Comment: You could implement your own exceptions and throw the relevant type where required.

Comment: Plutonix: Dim MyError As Exception = ex.InnerException() does not contain the value I require. 
Wheel73: I am not sure how to implement my own exceptions.

Comment: What exactly is it you are after? An exception can provide you with the actual exception that occurred, ex.Message() and the StackTrace. What additional info are you after. thanks

Comment: Why there is simply no way to drill into exception to get the data I require like

Dim myError as string = e.ErrorRecord.InnvocationInfo.PositionMessage

Comment: The hierarchy you show in your question is not that of a .NET Exception. It looks like [ErrorRecord Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0). Are you using PowerShell?

Comment: @djv: yes I use VB to run a powersheel script. PowerSheel script that I run occasionally returns expected error which I want to display in the application inside a textbox. While debuging I can see that information under "PositionMessage" so I wish to use it.

Comment: It can't be this simple... `ex.ErrorRecord.InvocationInfo.PositionM‌​essage`

Comment: @djv: If I could I would love to show you my issue or discuss it via hangout/chat. Maybe there is another way of doing it but the problem is interesting. I don't fully understand VB.net but I have to create an Application in that language, this is why my question looks not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception may be of type [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runtimeexception?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) in which case it implements `IContainsErrorRecord`. This means it has an ErrorRecord property (what you're looking for). You can try to cast it, and if it succeeds, you can access PositionMessage. Else (it's not a RuntimeException), then just treat it as a normal Exception.

```
Sub Main()
    Try
        ' do stuff
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim e = TryCast(ex, IContainsErrorRecord)
        Dim message As String
        If e IsNot Nothing Then
            message = e.ErrorRecord.InvocationInfo.PositionM‌​essage
        Else
            message = ex.Message
        End If
        Console.WriteLine(message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This works 100%. I actually need more data from ErrorRecord but I can use this logic to get this going! Thank you very much, I really appreciate your time and am sure that this will help to someone who is searching in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

NB: This is C#, but trivial to convert to VB. I do something like this:

```
results = pipeline.Invoke();

if (pipeline.Error.Count > 0)
{
       var errors = pipeline.Error.Read() as Collection<ErrorRecord>;
       if (errors != null)
       {
           foreach (ErrorRecord err in errors)
           {
                Console.WriteLine(err.InvocationMessage.PositionMessage);
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use telerik converter but is failing. 

I translated myself to something like this 
`'If (MyPipeline.Error.Count > 0) Then
  Dim errors As Collection(Of ErrorRecord) = MyPipeline.Error.Read()
If (errors IsNot Nothing) Then
For Each err As ErrorRecord In errors
 Next
End If
End If`

The problem was that I don't know where to put this in the code because when the PS is going to have the error this line
`Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()` crash the app so it never reaches the IF Condition to check the error count. Kudos for help!

Comment: I'm late to the party, as djv has already explained how to catch a terminating exception and do the necessary cast.